# How to speed up dijkstra Single source, single target with backtrack?

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I was trying to solve A Dijkstra problem [Alpha #20 Prob C](http://codeforces.com/contest/20/problem/C) and am getting TLE on Case 31, that has `100000` nodes with `99999` edges. I assume My code's complexity to be O(E lg V) which amounts to around `499995`. I assumed that to be fast enough, but due to unsuccessful results, I sped it up a little bit by using inline code for backtracking and some optimizations like breaking dijkstra as soon as the target node is deleted from the queue. I don't think that should affect the results, as if a node is deleted, that would mean that the best path has been found and we can go enjoy. I have now run out of ideas for optimizing this code, hence have arrived here. The code follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <cstdio>
#include <climits>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vii> vvii;

vi D;
vi parent;
vi path;
vvii graph;


void dijkstra(int i, int j)
{
        set<ii> Q;
        Q.insert(ii(0, i));
        D[i] = 0; parent[i] = -555;
        bool checked = false;
        while(!Q.empty())
        {
                ii top = *Q.begin();
            Q.erase(Q.begin());
            int topnode = top.second;
            for(vii::iterator it = graph[topnode].begin();it != graph[topnode].end();it++)
            {
                int v = it->first, d2 = it->second;
                if(D[v] > D[topnode] + d2)
                    {
                        if(D[v] != INT_MAX)
                        {
                                Q.erase(Q.find(ii(D[v], v)));
                        }
                        D[v] = D[topnode] + d2; parent[v] = topnode;
                        Q.insert(ii(D[v], v));
                        if(v == j)
                                checked = true;
                    }
            }
            if(checked)
            {
                if(Q.find(ii(D[j], j)) == Q.end())
                    break;
            }
        }
}

/* void backtrack(int n)
{
    if(parent[n] != -555)
    {
        path.push_back(n);
        backtrack(parent[n]);
    }
}

void backtrack2(int n)
{
    while(parent[n] != -555)
    {
        path.push_back(n);
        n = parent[n];
    }
} */

int main(void) {
    int n, m, x, y, z;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    graph.clear(); graph.resize(n); D.resize(n, INT_MAX); parent.resize(n, -1);
    while(m--)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &x, &y, &z);
        graph[x-1].push_back(ii(y-1, z));
        graph[y-1].push_back(ii(x-1, z));
    }
    dijkstra(0, n-1);
    if(D[n-1] == INT_MAX)
        printf("-1\n");
    else
    {
        int x = n-1;
        while(parent[x] != -555)
        {
            path.push_back(x);
            x = parent[x];
        }
        printf("1 ");
        for(int i = int(path.size())-1;i >= 0;i--)
        {
            printf("%d ", path[i]+1);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is it that I can do to improve it's speed. I've tried decreasing recursive calls overhead and a lot more that's possible. If anyone has any other ideas, or can point out some kind of mistake(if any(in optimisations)) would be highly appreciatted. the only thing now I think can be done, is the use of priority_queue(instead of set), but I don't think that'll affect the performance much.

Thanks!

nib

Comment: Have a look at this, dijkstra using priority queue https://ronzii.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/dijkstras-algorithm-using-stl/

Comment: @g4ur4v thanks really, I know about using priority queue for speed, but I just checked the [Topcoder Tutorial of STL](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=standardTemplateLibrary2) and it says that using `set` instead of `priority_queue` in dijkstra has ~0.1% difference, which I seriously doubt can help in this case. Also, I already mentioned of the optimization in the last para myself...

Comment: One possible speedup is to merge multiple edges between the same vertices on graph creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution seems mostly fine to me, and `O(E log V)` for this constraints is more than enough.

Your problem is most likely due to the fact that you use integers, and in particular that you use `INT_MAX` as something that is bigger than any possible path length. With `10^5` edges and weights up to a million `int` is just not enough. And as soon as you overflow and get negative weights, all the dijkstra invariants break, and it is not even guaranteed to terminate.

Replace all the `int`s with `long long`s, and `INT_MAX` with something bigger than `10^11`, and your solution will most likely pass.